# How to use a QVector?

Tags: c++, qt

Let's say I have a class with the following member

```
QVector<bool> m_vector;
```

Then on the constructor I can do

```
m_vector.resize(SIZE);
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    m_vector[i] = false;
```

or (shorter)

```
m_vector = QVector(SIZE, false);
```

The shorter approch is shorter and shorter is better? Or the assingment operator tells me there is a (unnecessary) copy going on and I should prefer the non shorter approch?

Comment: I think you have a mistake in the for cycle, you probably want to use 'm_vector[i] = false'

Comment: Not anymore, thanks bro!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either approach works fine, but the second/shorter approach is preferred, since it requires less code and therefore provides fewer opportunities for getting something wrong.  As for performance, the "unnecessary copy" will almost certainly be implemented as a construct-and-[move](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#operator-eq-1) rather than a copy (since `QVector(SIZE, false)` is an rvalue), which means it's not significantly less efficient than your first example.  In particular, the array of SIZE elements would be stolen from the temporary `QVector` object and given to `m_vector` to adopt, rather than being (created, copied-over, and then destroyed).

That said, the most optimal way to do it is to instead initialize your `m_vector` object in your class-constructor's initializer-list, like this:

```
MyClass :: MyClass()
    : m_vector(SIZE, false)
{
}
```

... that way the resizing/default-filling is done as part of `m_vector`'s original construction, rather than as a separate step aftwerwards.